# Reails remote form format exists but not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-with

The following form intends to generate an XHR response

```
<% articlediscounts_for_article = @articlediscounts.where(article_id: article.id).first %>
<%= form_with(scope: articlediscounts_for_article, url: user_discount_users_path, local: false, method: :post) do |form| %>
```

the action processes

```
Processing by UsersController#user_discount as JS
```

and generates expected results, but fails in the rendering process, complaining about (with initial stack)

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (UsersController#user_discount is missing a template for this request format and variant. 

request.formats: ["text/javascript", "*/*"]
request.variant: []):
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:42:in `default_render'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `block in send_action'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `tap'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
```

Yet that template clearly exists in the proper path  (its corresponding partial is also present in the directory) as shown here:

[image: template in directory]

This is perplexing as the warning message is contrary to the reality.  The only assumptions that come to mind are that of some handling of `form_with` cmobined with the `scope` or the question of variant

What is mistaken here?

Comment: This is going to be impossible for anyone else to replicate. Go through everything again and attempt to isolate the problem by creating a minimal verifiable reproducable example. By doing so you'll usually solve the problem on your own which can be stuff like VC issues or that your didn't actually place the file where you think you did.

Comment: Can you put in the controller code for the method, it *could help?

Comment: @RockwellRice I don't really think it makes any difference at all - we can see from the log snippet that rails is rendering implicitly - so there is no explicit render call or anything else to blame. Unless the view lookup paths are messed up some way my money is on simple programmer error.

Comment: Yes, as an issue it is difficule to isolate and replicate.  Moving the actions to another controller reached the desired end-result, whereas changing action and file names (yes, the files are there) within the existing controller would generate the same response, thus there is an issue within the controller. Now considering `devise` matters...